# Maximum items to retain after removing k items from array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers, I want to delete k items such that they are next to each other such that the number of distinct elements in the array after deletion is maximum.

**Example:**

**Input:**

```
arr = [2,3,1,1,2]
k = 2
```

**Ans:** 3

**Explanation:**

Remove elements at index 3 & 4 which are 1 and 2 in array. Then array becomes [2,3,1] so it has 3 different elements.

This is my code:

```
int delete(int[] arr, int k) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int max = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - k + 1; i++) {
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    j = j + k - 1;
                } else {
                    set.add(arr[j]);
                }
            }
            max = Math.max(set.size(), max);
        }

        return max;
    }
```

How to reduce the time complexity for this problem. Because the size of array can be upto 1000000 and also the size of k is upto the array size. Each arraycelement can be upto 1000000

Comment: Are you certain your statement and example are accurate.  If you can only remove k items and the k items are adjacent they why even mention anything about a maximum?  If the array is of size N and you can remove K then wouldn't the resulting size be N-K?

Comment: @WJS, My problem statement is "the number of distinct elements in the array after deletion is maximum" so the unique count should be maximum.

Comment: Can you provide a somewhat more complex example.  What about the fact that the k items are adjacent in the array (according to your question).  And you say you're removing `k`, a fixed number.  How can the result be anything other than `N-k` items?

Comment: @WJS, example N = 8 , arr = [5,5,5,6,6,6,3,3], k = 2. So I will delete values at index 0 & 1 then array becomes [5,6,6,6,3,3] . The unique items are 5,6,3 so output is 3. But N-K = 8-2 = 6.

Comment: Exactly.  But you didn't show that kind of array in the example.   And with the just given example, you don't explain how you chose 0 and 1 (I presume because they were the first duplicates encountered) or what the next ones to delete would be., And so on until the final array is determined.  But apparently, I am the only one who didn't understand what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in O(N): It uses a map containing the number of occurrences of each number:

You start by filling the map with the elements from k to n-1 (in other words, the array without the first k elements), then you iterate and the first element and remove the last.

```
static int delete2(int[] arr, int k) {
    int n = arr.length;
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = k; i < n; i++) {
        Integer value = arr[i];
        if (!map.containsKey(value)) {
            map.put(value, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(value, map.get(value)+1);
        }
    }
    int max = map.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n-k; ++i) {
        Integer value = arr[i];
        if (!map.containsKey(value)) {
            map.put(value, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(value, map.get(value)+1);
        }
        value = arr[i+k];
        Integer count = map.get(value);
        if (count == 1) {
            map.remove(value);
        } else {
            map.put(value, count-1);
        }
        max = Math.max(map.size(), max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: @josejuan But they are not "are next to each other" (continuous subarray, as far as I understand). Seems you are solving not the same problem

Comment: You are right and I'm wrong @MBo (thank you for show my error).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to delete k adjacent elements such that the resulting set of set of arr - k elements is as large as possible.

Just test each candidate set (there are n sets to try).

So something like this should work

```
int delete(int[] arr, int k) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int max = -1;
        Set<Integer> rem = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
             rem.add(arr[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n - k + 1; i++) {
            Set<Integer> candidate = new HashSet<>();
            for (int j = i; j < i + k; j++) {
                    candidate.add(arr[j]);
            }
            rem.removeAll(candidate);
            if (rem.size() > max){
                max = rem.size();
            } else {
                candidate.forEach((e) -> {
                    rem.add(e);
                });
            }
        }
        // you could also return the actual candidate set that produces the maximum
        return max;
    }
```

The set operation in the loop are all order `k`. So resulting time is order `n*k`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int delete(int[] arr, int k) {
    // step 1: traverse the array exactly once and make a hashtable
    //   with counts of each unique element
    Map<Integer, Integer> elemCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int e : arr) {
        int ct = elemCounts.getOrDefault(e, 0);
        elemCounts.put(e, ct + 1);
    }
    // step 2: traverse through the array exactly once more, and
    //   keep track of the adjacent elements which produce the least 
    //   disturbance. 
    // step 2a: for the first k elements, see what removing them would
    //   do to the overall uniqueness of the array
    int numPermanentRemovals = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int ct = elemCounts.get(arr[i]);
        elemCounts.put(arr[i], ct - 1);
        if (ct - 1 == 0) {
            numPermanentRemovals += 1;
        }
    }
    // step 2b: for the remainder of the array, track the rolling
    //   numPermanentRemovals for k adjacent elements
    int minDisruption = numPermanentRemovals;
    int minDisruptionIndex = 0;
    for (int i = k; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // put back the element at the start of the current window
        int stct = elemCounts.get(arr[i - k]);
        elemCounts.put(arr[i - k], stct + 1);
        if (stct == 0) {
            numPermanentRemovals -= 1;
        }
        // take out the element being added to the new window
        int edct = elemCounts.get(arr[i]);
        elemCounts.put(arr[i], edct - 1);
        if (edct - 1 == 0) {
            numPermanentRemovals += 1;
        }
        // if this minimum disruption index is a new floor, then
        // replace the original
        if (numPermanentRemovals < minDisruption) {
            minDisruption = numPermanentRemovals;
            minDisruptionIndex = i - k + 1;
        }
        // short-circuit if we find a perfect solution
        if (minDisruption == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return minDisruptionIndex;
}
```